# A problem on number of injections from a set to the same set

Tags: combinatorics, functions, relations

Let a set be defined as $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $f: A \to A$ such that for all $i$ in $A$, at least one $f(i) = i$. How many such injective functions exist?

My approach:

As at least one $f(i) = i$, total number of injective functions is the same as sum of all injective functions where number of fixed elements lies between $1$ and $5$.

- If one element fixed for which $f(i) = i$ and no others:

> Let $(1,1)$ be fixed, number of functions is $(3 \times 2  \times 1)$.

> There are $5$ such functions, where one of the five elements is fixed, total is $6 \times 5 = 30$.

I am unable to apply this logic where two or more pairs are fixed, for example $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ and no others such that $f(i) = i$. How can this be solved?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could just count the number of the injections such that $f(i) \neq i$ for all $i$. Have you looked into derangements?

Comment: The number of injective functions for which $1$ is the only fixed point is $9$, not $6$. For instance, there are three functions with $f(2)=3$, namely: the vector $(f(3),f(4),f(5))$ may be $(2,5,4)$ or $(4,5,2)$ or $(5,2,4)$. Likewise there are three functions with $f(2)=4$ and three with $f(2)=5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the event that $f(i) = i$

We want to find $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{5}A_i$

By Inclusion-Exclusion and symmetry of events, this equals
$${5 \choose 1}A_1  - {5 \choose 2}(A_1\cap A_2) + {5\choose3}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) - {5 \choose 4}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) + 1$$

Counting the events is straightforward since now we don't need to consider the cases in which f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2 and no other f(i) = i

Comment: What about the previous one?

Comment: Counting directly doesn't work since f(1) = 1 does not imply 3! functions. Why? Because f(2) does have 3 choices, yes, but f(3) can also have 3 choices if f(2) = 3 (2, 4, 5) or 2 choices otherwise (4, 5). So if you wish to count "directly", enumerating all valid combinations would be the most direct.